# Why does this recursive addition return none

Tags: python-3.x

This is a weird one print return 9 and then it prints 1 , also i checked debugger in pycharm and the (stuff) keeps counting down for some reason

```
def repeater(stuff):
    if stuff != 9:
        stuff += 1
        print(stuff)
        repeater(stuff)
    return stuff

print(repeater(0))
```

Comment: You're missing `stuff = repeater(stuff)` or `return repeater(stuff)` (I'm not really sure what you want to do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `repeater(stuff)`, you're not passing the variable `stuff`, you're passing a *copy of* the variable `stuff`. When you say `stuff += 1`, you're not modifying the `stuff` you called the function with, you're modifying a copy of it. That change isn't reflected in the original when you exit the function.

Then, when the function exits, you don't *do* anything with the returned value of `stuff` - which is, again, copied out of the function in reverse. Python does let you call the function without using its return value, but it looks like your intent here is to apply the returned value of `repeater(stuff)` to `stuff`.

To accomplish that, simply change the line

```
repeater(stuff)
```

to

```
stuff = repeater(stuff)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that additional `1` that is coming in the end is that `repeater(stuff)` is returning the value of `stuff` which is being received by your print statement i.e. `print(repeater(0))`. When all the recursive calls return back, none of the values are stored/used but the very first call that was made by `print(repeater(0))` obtains a value of `1` because `repeater(stuff)` returns the value of stuff which would be `1` after `stuff += 1` during the first call.

You can read more about how recursion works for more clarity.